# Create a translucent plastic node setup/bump map for "ice pack" material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, bump

Looking to recreate this rough polyethylene material with a "gel" ish appearance underneath.  Any help is appreciated!  Thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *Noise Texture* to make the blue and white texture, plug it into the *Subsurface Scattering* socket of the *Principled BSDF* to make the object semi-translucent, plug the texture into a *Bump* node to give a bit of relief on the surface. I also used *Vertex Paint > Dirty Vertex Colors* to keep the angles without ice:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This should be rather simple. Just use a noise texture (softened by runiing through a MixRGB with white) and a Bump Node to get the surface bumps. Then, create the "icy" (translucent) gel effect by using a small Subsurface Value (0.3) and a blue color.

[image: IcePack]

If you want to go deeper on the gel effect, try increasing the blue and green values only of your Subsurface Radius:

[image: Gel]

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to the other answers here, I think one of the interesting things about this object is that the plastic is thicker on the corners, and that blocks the gel from showing through.

[image]

I'm using a node group similar to the others.  I've just inverted the noise texture using a Color Ramp, and I'm using that to determine where subsurface scattering should happen.  Where the noise texture is near 1, the bump node is making the model appear as though the plastic is thicker.  By inverting it we're letting the blue color come through on the thinner parts.  We can also use the Pointiness output of the geometry node to identify corners and subtract some amount from our subsurface scattering.

[image]

Be aware that the pointiness output works better with an appropriate amount of subdivisions.

[image]